# PHP - Why am I getting this error? Call to undefined function

Tags: php

I am new to php, so sorry if this is lame.

I have a simple class that has two private functions. For some reason when I try to call `_sendInvalidEmailNotice()` I get an error stating that the function is undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class Mail extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this - > load - > helper('email');
    }

    function _sendMessage($message) {
        send_email('name@gmail.com', 'Test Email', $message);
        $success = array('success' = > 'Mail Sent');
        echo json_encode($success);
    }

    function _sendInvalidEmailNotice() {
        $errorMessage = array('error' = > 'Invalid Email Address');
        echo json_encode($errorMessage);
    }

    public
    function sendMail($returnAddress, $message) {
        if (valid_email($returnAddress)) {
            _sendMessage($message);
        } else {
            _sendInvalidEmailNotice();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add context.

```
$this->_sendInvalidEmailNotice();
```

Comment: I didn't realize that was necessary in PHP. Thanks!

Comment: It is because you're in the context of a class.  No problem, happy coding.  : )